# Django site performance problem

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, django, mod-wsgi

my mod_wsgi/django app has ~2s response time with or without memcached in-memory caching.

response is the same 2s with or without DNS resolution (i.e. with direct IP request)

for comparison, a simulaneously running mediawiki php process running with APC has sub-second response.

the machine is not out of memory and I can tell that memcached uses up some space.

I've seen the same django app run twice faster on some other machine (of which I unfortunately know little details, but it seems to be running on webfactional) my machine is dedicated host.

here is my apache directive to run the app

```
<VirtualHost ...:80>
     ServerAdmin ...
     DocumentRoot ...
     ServerName ..
     WSGIScriptAlias / /../wsgi-script.wsgi
     CustomLog ... common
     ErrorLog /.../error_log
     DirectoryIndex index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT** ok found the source of the problem - wsgi was **[serving static files](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Hosting_Of_Static_Files)** and that's what drained the performance. Some Alias-type directives for static content fix the issue.

Comment: So, could you please share how you fixed it?

Comment: add Alias directive to connect static files urls with a directory where your static files are.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the built-in development server?  Last time I checked that wasn't really meant for production.  Consider using Apache with mod_wsgi if that is the case.  [Here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/) are the instructions.

Comment: with both apache/wsgi and dev server. speed is the same, thanks